# Bundle files after aot with angular 2 cli

Tags: javascript, apache, angular

I am getting my app ready for production. The thing is that `ng build --prod --aot` creates many files. `inline.js`, `main.js` are in MB. Also there are `.gz` files with smaller size. I am working with an Apache server.

Do I need to upload the whole `dist` folder?
How can I use `.gz` instead of `.js`? 
In my `dist/index.html` there are generated links for the `.js` files. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a webpage, gzip is a configuration method in your web server. The file is gzipped by the server, sent to the browser. No manual action is needed. For Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html.

If you are delivering the code to developers, you could use the gzip command.

Comment: I need to upload those .gz to the server instead of .js if its possible

Comment: You can configure it in server and follow the link above I provided then you will be able to upload `.gz` and server will handle automatically.